# How to have a custom control pull over all required files when used from Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, custom-controls

I have created a custom control for my development team to utilize the CefSharp Chromium Web Browser. I have everything setup and working well. The only problem is having it run for projects that do not directly reference the chrome project in their solution.

I would like to find a way for when a developer drag and drops my custom control into their application, it will automatically copy ALL of the required files from the compiled control to their bin folder.

Currently, it only pulls the handle full directly referenced by the tool, but some are utilized at run time due to limitation of the utility for being able to compile for Any CPU efficiently.

[Image of Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/107eR.png)

I would like to have all of the files on the left hand side be copied automatically upon using the control from the tool box to the appropriate folder, or at the very least at run time.

Any information or ideas on where to look are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your current project?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, though this feels like back practice.

My issue what using CefSharp and getting all of the x64 and x84 files downloaded where ever require. I ended up adding a zip file of each content and then extracting them at run time as needed.